# scrollHeight + 60 doesn't work for me javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code so far:

```
interestedP.animate({'max-height': (interestedP[0].scrollHeight + 60 + 'px')}, "slow");
```

It works also without 'px', but +60 never gets to work out. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
interestedP.animate({'max-height': (interestedP[0].scrollHeight + 60) + 'px'}, "slow");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C7Npf/)

Comment: my problem is because of max-height :) if I had used height instead it would be easy. But I can't use height because I need elastic height when content is small.

Comment: I don't think you can animate `max-height`

Comment: I used padding-bottom instead of adding 60px to the calculation of the height. Works now. ty for help.